# How to share files tortoise svn?

Tags: svn, repository

i install tortoise-svn and I know how to commit and update the files in tortoise-SVN but I did not know how to connect other computer to my computer, I know some server I have to used but there is no tutorial to setting and download the svn server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest -- if all other users can `ssh` into the server then you can just use `svn+ssh://server/path/...` on remove machines to work with the repository.

Somewhat simple -- start an instance of [`svnserve`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svnserve.html).

Non trivial but the most scalable and strategically right way -- run a web server with SVN module. Fortunately there is a "for dummies" edition of this [freely available](http://www.collab.net/downloads/subversion).

Comment: anonymous downvoter - is it a revenge for some other question?